# How can I style nodes in Memgraph Lab?

Tags: memgraphdb

I want to change the color and size of nodes from the default values. I have a huge resolution and I need to zoom in a lot to see what I want. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. I need to use the following code:

```
@NodeStyle {
  size: 100
  border-width: 10
}
```